# How can I strip out all HTML from my string

Tags: java, android

When I save text from an EditText I save it with `Html.toHtml(editable);`

Now I need to display the text but without the HTML and not in an EditText or TextView

I need to display it in a notification bar notification so I need all the HTML gone.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTicker("You have a recieved a message. " +Html.fromHtml(message).toString()) // html still showing
```

Comment: What do you mean by "html still showing"?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.text.Html.fromHtml(string).toString()
```

This worked.